# How to find the image of a matrix by a transformation in Mathematica

Tags: matrix, coordinate-transformation

I have searched for image of a matrix, but I just get graphics-related results here.

So I try to make a  new post:

Let

```
 m2={{4,-9},{4,-8}}
```

Express the image $x\rightarrow Ax$ on $R^2$ with the corresponding matrix in the base $B= {b_1, b_2}$, where $b_1=[3,2]$ and $b_2=[2,1]$.

How does one do that in Mathematica?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at `RowReduce` and `LinearSolve`

Comment: Thanks, will do